# Macro that export complete row data based on column name to new excel file getting error in that

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ExportCreatePOD()

'File names to be created as " & " " & "-" & " " & "POL" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now()," MM-DD-YYYY ")"


    Dim RngSourceData As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    Dim RngRange02 As Range
    Dim StrCarrierColumnHeader As String
    Dim StrSavePath As String
    Dim StrMultipleFileMessage As String
    Dim DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn As Double
    Dim DblCounter01 As Double
    Dim DblCounter02 As Double
    Dim WkbSource As Workbook
    Dim WkbTarget As Workbook
    
    'Turning off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set WkbSource = ActiveWorkbook
    Set RngSourceData = WkbSource.Sheets("POD").UsedRange
    StrCarrierColumnHeader = "Carrier"
    StrSavePath = "C:Path\" '=== Path for POD files Change the Path (where you want to export the POD files)
    
  
    On Error Resume Next
    DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(StrCarrierColumnHeader, RngSourceData.Rows(1), 0)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The range " & RngSourceData.Rows(1).Address(False, False) & " contains no column headed " & StrCarrierColumnHeader & ". The subroutine is terminated", vbCritical, "Error"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
  
    Set RngRange01 = RngSourceData.Columns(DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn).Resize(RngSourceData.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0)
    

    DblCounter01 = 0
    For Each RngTarget In RngRange01.Cells
        

        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngSourceData.Parent.Range(RngRange01.Cells(1, 1), RngTarget), RngTarget.Value) = 1 Then
            
            'Cheking if any file dedicated to the given carrier already exists for today.
            If Dir(StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POD" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & ".xlsx") = "" Then
                'If no such file exists, it is created and saved.
                Set WkbTarget = Workbooks.Add
                WkbTarget.SaveAs StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POD" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & ".xlsx"
            Else
                'Is it does exist, the name is "shifted".
                DblCounter02 = 2
                Do Until Dir(StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POD" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx") = ""
                    DblCounter02 = DblCounter02 + 1
                Loop
                'Carrier and relative file are copied in StrMultipleFileMessage.
                StrMultipleFileMessage = StrMultipleFileMessage & vbCrLf & RngTarget.Value & " in " & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POD" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx"
                Set WkbTarget = Workbooks.Add
                WkbTarget.SaveAs StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POD" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx"
            End If
            
            'Setting RngRange02 to target the range in the new file where RngSourceData will be copied.
            Set RngRange02 = WkbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(RngSourceData.Rows.Count, RngSourceData.Columns.Count)
            
            With RngRange02
                
                'Copying values.
                RngSourceData.Copy RngRange02
                
                'Filtering the range to clear the list of unwanted data.
                .AutoFilter Field:=DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn, Criteria1:="<>" & RngTarget.Value
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).ClearFormats
                
                'Removing the filter.
                .AutoFilter
                
                'Rename Sheet
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "POD"
                 
                 'Autofit
                
                Sheets("POD").UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
                
          
               
                
                'Sorting the range to compact the data.
                With .Parent.Sort
                     .SortFields.Clear
                     .SortFields.Add Key:=RngRange02.Columns(DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn), _
                                    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                    Order:=xlAscending, _
                                    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    .SetRange RngRange02
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With
                
      
                
            End With
            
            'Saving and closing WkbTarget.
            WkbTarget.Close SaveChanges:=True
            
        End If
        
        'Setting DblCounter01.
        DblCounter01 = DblCounter01 + 1
    Next
    
    'Enabling screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'Reporting if any carrier had its data reported in a "twin" file.
    If StrMultipleFileMessage <> "" Then
        StrMultipleFileMessage = "The following carriers had already one or more dedicated files at the given path. Their data were saved accordingly to this list:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & StrMultipleFileMessage
        MsgBox StrMultipleFileMessage, , "Multiple dedicated files"
    End If

End Sub
```

I created a macro that split data based on column name "Carrier" into a new excel file. I have 2 tabs named POL and POD for which I created 2 sets of codes that split data from these tabs based on the column name and created a new excel file, my code for tab POL is working but not for POD. I neither get any error it just executes and create a file but does not paste any data of the POD tab.

[Main Excel File which has Macro codes Problem in Tab POD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf8AT.png)

In this above screen, you can see the POD tab has so much data that macro should create a new file based on column name "Carrier". When I execute the macro it create a new file but there is no data in it meaning the data does not get captured in the newly created POD file. I am pasting the output as follows.

[Wrong Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqmNW.png)

If you see in the above image no data is captured in the newly created file.

I will paste my complete code below the codes for both the tabs POL and POD. Please guide is there any easy way to cut short the codes that read both POL and POD tabs and create/splits the data into a new excel file based on the column named carrier. However, at present, the problem is with the codes within "
Sub ExportCreatePOD()"

My Complete Codes :-

'--------------------------------Create POL POD XL Sheets---------------------------

```
Sub ExportCreatePOL()

'File names to be created as " & " " & "-" & " " & "POL" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now()," MM-DD-YYYY ")"

    Dim RngSourceData As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    Dim RngRange02 As Range
    Dim StrCarrierColumnHeader As String
    Dim StrSavePath As String
    Dim StrMultipleFileMessage As String
    Dim DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn As Double
    Dim DblCounter01 As Double
    Dim DblCounter02 As Double
    Dim WkbSource As Workbook
    Dim WkbTarget As Workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set WkbSource = ActiveWorkbook
    Set RngSourceData = WkbSource.Sheets("POL").UsedRange
    StrCarrierColumnHeader = "Carrier"
    StrSavePath = "C:Path\" '===Path where excel files will be created Change the Path (where you want to export the POL files)
    
    'Setting DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn to determine what column within RngSourceData _
    contains the StrCarrierColumnHeader. If no such column is found, the subroutine is terminated.
    On Error Resume Next
    DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(StrCarrierColumnHeader, RngSourceData.Rows(1), 0)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The range " & RngSourceData.Rows(1).Address(False, False) & " contains no column headed " & StrCarrierColumnHeader & ". The subroutine is terminated", vbCritical, "Error"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set RngRange01 = RngSourceData.Columns(DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn).Resize(RngSourceData.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0)
   
    DblCounter01 = 0
    For Each RngTarget In RngRange01.Cells
        
        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngSourceData.Parent.Range(RngRange01.Cells(1, 1), RngTarget), RngTarget.Value) = 1 Then
            
     
            If Dir(StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POL" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & ".xlsx") = "" Then
          
                Set WkbTarget = Workbooks.Add
                
                WkbTarget.SaveAs StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POL" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & ".xlsx"
            Else
                'Is it does exist, the name is "shifted".
                DblCounter02 = 2
                Do Until Dir(StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POL" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx") = ""
                    DblCounter02 = DblCounter02 + 1
                Loop
                'Carrier and relative file are copied in StrMultipleFileMessage.
                StrMultipleFileMessage = StrMultipleFileMessage & vbCrLf & RngTarget.Value & " in " & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POL" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx"
                
                Set WkbTarget = Workbooks.Add
                
                WkbTarget.SaveAs StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POL" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx"
            End If
            
            'Setting RngRange02 to target the range in the new file where RngSourceData will be copied.
            Set RngRange02 = WkbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(RngSourceData.Rows.Count, RngSourceData.Columns.Count)
            
            With RngRange02
                
                'Copying values.
                RngSourceData.Copy RngRange02
                
                'Filtering the range to clear the list of unwanted data.
                .AutoFilter Field:=DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn, Criteria1:="<>" & RngTarget.Value
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).ClearFormats
                
                'Removing the filter.
                .AutoFilter
  
                'Rename sheet1
                Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "POL"
                
                                        
                'Autofit
                
                Sheets("POL").UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
                
                          
                'Sorting the range to compact the data.
                With .Parent.Sort
                     .SortFields.Clear
                     .SortFields.Add Key:=RngRange02.Columns(DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn), _
                                    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                    Order:=xlAscending, _
                                    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    .SetRange RngRange02
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                    
                End With
                
                
            End With
            
            'Saving and closing WkbTarget.
            WkbTarget.Close SaveChanges:=True
            
        End If
        
        'Setting DblCounter01.
        DblCounter01 = DblCounter01 + 1
    Next
    
    'Enabling screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'Reporting if any carrier had its data reported in a "twin" file.
    If StrMultipleFileMessage <> "" Then
        StrMultipleFileMessage = "The following carriers had already one or more dedicated files at the given path. Their data were saved accordingly to this list:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & StrMultipleFileMessage
        MsgBox StrMultipleFileMessage, , "Multiple dedicated files"
    End If
    
    End Sub



Sub ExportCreatePOD()

'File names to be created as " & " " & "-" & " " & "POL" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now()," MM-DD-YYYY ")"


    Dim RngSourceData As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    Dim RngRange02 As Range
    Dim StrCarrierColumnHeader As String
    Dim StrSavePath As String
    Dim StrMultipleFileMessage As String
    Dim DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn As Double
    Dim DblCounter01 As Double
    Dim DblCounter02 As Double
    Dim WkbSource As Workbook
    Dim WkbTarget As Workbook
    
    'Turning off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set WkbSource = ActiveWorkbook
    Set RngSourceData = WkbSource.Sheets("POD").UsedRange
    StrCarrierColumnHeader = "Carrier"
    StrSavePath = "C:Path\" '=== Path for POD files Change the Path (where you want to export the POD files)
    
  
    On Error Resume Next
    DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(StrCarrierColumnHeader, RngSourceData.Rows(1), 0)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The range " & RngSourceData.Rows(1).Address(False, False) & " contains no column headed " & StrCarrierColumnHeader & ". The subroutine is terminated", vbCritical, "Error"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
  
    Set RngRange01 = RngSourceData.Columns(DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn).Resize(RngSourceData.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0)
    

    DblCounter01 = 0
    For Each RngTarget In RngRange01.Cells
        

        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngSourceData.Parent.Range(RngRange01.Cells(1, 1), RngTarget), RngTarget.Value) = 1 Then
            
            'Cheking if any file dedicated to the given carrier already exists for today.
            If Dir(StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POD" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & ".xlsx") = "" Then
                'If no such file exists, it is created and saved.
                Set WkbTarget = Workbooks.Add
                WkbTarget.SaveAs StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POD" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & ".xlsx"
            Else
                'Is it does exist, the name is "shifted".
                DblCounter02 = 2
                Do Until Dir(StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POD" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx") = ""
                    DblCounter02 = DblCounter02 + 1
                Loop
                'Carrier and relative file are copied in StrMultipleFileMessage.
                StrMultipleFileMessage = StrMultipleFileMessage & vbCrLf & RngTarget.Value & " in " & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POD" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx"
                Set WkbTarget = Workbooks.Add
                WkbTarget.SaveAs StrSavePath & RngTarget.Value & " " & "-" & " " & "POD" & " " & "-" & " " & Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ") & "(" & DblCounter02 & ")" & ".xlsx"
            End If
            
            'Setting RngRange02 to target the range in the new file where RngSourceData will be copied.
            Set RngRange02 = WkbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(RngSourceData.Rows.Count, RngSourceData.Columns.Count)
            
            With RngRange02
                
                'Copying values.
                RngSourceData.Copy RngRange02
                
                'Filtering the range to clear the list of unwanted data.
                .AutoFilter Field:=DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn, Criteria1:="<>" & RngTarget.Value
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).ClearFormats
                
                'Removing the filter.
                .AutoFilter
                
                'Rename Sheet
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "POD"
                 
                 'Autofit
                
                Sheets("POD").UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
                
          
               
                
                'Sorting the range to compact the data.
                With .Parent.Sort
                     .SortFields.Clear
                     .SortFields.Add Key:=RngRange02.Columns(DblCarrierColumnRelativeColumn), _
                                    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                    Order:=xlAscending, _
                                    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    .SetRange RngRange02
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With
                
      
                
            End With
            
            'Saving and closing WkbTarget.
            WkbTarget.Close SaveChanges:=True
            
        End If
        
        'Setting DblCounter01.
        DblCounter01 = DblCounter01 + 1
    Next
    
    'Enabling screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'Reporting if any carrier had its data reported in a "twin" file.
    If StrMultipleFileMessage <> "" Then
        StrMultipleFileMessage = "The following carriers had already one or more dedicated files at the given path. Their data were saved accordingly to this list:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & StrMultipleFileMessage
        MsgBox StrMultipleFileMessage, , "Multiple dedicated files"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Side Note: Why use so many &? Isn't it easier as `& " - POL - " &`

Comment: Does `WkbSource.Sheets("POD").UsedRange` return a non-blank range?

Comment: @Toddleson Yea! " - POL - " will be much easier than what I coded.
Yes! WkbSource.Sheets("POD").UsedRange returns a non-blank range

Comment: If you pause execution before the autofilter stuff, is there any data in the file? I'm thinking it might all be getting deleted by the `.ClearContents`

Comment: Please some1 answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are copying all the data, filtering and then deleting unwanted records I suspect the problem is with the data. Try this more direct approach of copying only what you want.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportCreateBoth()
    Call ExportCreateFile("POD")
    Call ExportCreateFile("POL")
End Sub

Sub ExportCreateFile(ws_name As String)

    Const COL_NAME = "Carrier"
    Const SAVEPATH = "C:\temp\so\" ' ouput folder

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbOut As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, r As Long
    Dim iCol As Integer, iLastCol As Integer, iLastRow As Long
    Dim filename As String, msg As String

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(ws_name)
    iLastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").Resize(1, iLastCol).Find(COL_NAME)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        msg = "The range " & ws.Rows(1).Address() & " contains no column headed " _
        & COL_NAME & ". The subroutine is terminated"
        MsgBox msg, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' carrier column
    iCol = rng.Column
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").Resize(iLastRow, iLastCol)

    ' create list of unique values
    Dim dict, key
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 2 To iLastRow
        key = Trim(ws.Cells(r, iCol))
        If Len(key) > 0 Then dict(key) = 1
    Next
 
    ' create workbooks for each carrier
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each key In dict.keys

        ' create output workbook
        filename = GetFileName(SAVEPATH, key, ws_name, msg)
        Set wbOut = Workbooks.Add
        Set wsOut = wbOut.Sheets(1)
        wsOut.Name = ws_name

        ' copy filtered data
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=CStr(key)
        rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
             wsOut.Range("A1")
             wsOut.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
        wbOut.SaveAs filename
        wbOut.Close False
        rng.AutoFilter
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        msg = "The following carriers had already one or more " & _
          "dedicated files at the given path. " & _
          "Their data were saved accordingly to this list:" & msg & vbCrLf
        MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, "Multiple dedicated files"
    End If

    MsgBox dict.Count & " files created for " & ws_name, vbInformation
End Sub

Function GetFileName(folder, carrier, str, ByRef msg) As String

    Const EXT = ".xlsx"
    Dim mdy As String, filename As String, s As String, n As Integer
    
    mdy = Format(Now(), " MM-DD-YYYY ")
    filename = folder & carrier & " - " & str & " - " & mdy
    s = filename & EXT
    n = 1
    Do Until Dir(s) = ""
        s = filename & "(" & n & ")" & EXT
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    If n > 1 Then
        msg = msg & vbLf & carrier & " in " & s
    End If
    GetFileName = s

End Function
```